# message and video sharing youtube php

Tags: php, youtube

i want to get user's inbox of youtube and send a video messsage. below is the code i am using to retrieve inbox. inbox comes shows that inbox of user XXXX but inbox is empty, no messages comes. while i have four video messages in my inbox.

```
$developer_key='REPLACE_ME';
$client_id= 'REPLACE_ME';
$client_secret='REPLACE_ME';

// error checking; user might have denied access
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    if ($_GET['error'] == 'access_denied') {
        echo('You have denied access. Click <a href="'. $_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"] .'">here</a> to retry&hellip;');
    } else {
        echo("An error has occurred: ". $_GET['error']);
    }
    exit;
}

// Step 1: redirect to google account login if necessary
if(!isset($_GET['code']) || $_GET['code'] === '') { 
    Header('Location: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id='. $client_id .
            '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Test/sendMessage.php' .
            '&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline',
        true, 307);
    exit;
}
$authorization_code= $_GET['code'];

// Step 2: use authorization code to get access token
$url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$message_post= 'code='. $authorization_code .
        '&client_id='. $client_id . 
        '&client_secret='. $client_secret .
        '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/Test/sendMessage.php' .
        '&grant_type=authorization_code';


$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $message_post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo "<pre>";
echo "<br><br> message_post : ";
print_r($result);
if ($cur_error= curl_error($ch)) {
    echo($cur_error);
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;
}
curl_close($ch);

$jsonArray= json_decode($result, true);

if ($jsonArray === null) {
    echo("Could not decode JSON.");
    exit;
}

if (isset($jsonArray['error'])) {
    echo("An error has occurred: ". $jsonArray['error']);
    exit;
}

if (!isset($jsonArray['access_token'])) {
    echo("Access token not found.");
    exit;
}


//The user's authentication token
$access_token= $jsonArray['access_token'];
$title ='krishna'; //The title of the caption track
$lang = 'en'; //The languageof the caption track
//$transcript = $_REQUEST['transcript']; //The caption file data
$inboxUrl ='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/inbox?alt=json&&key=AIzaSyBeh0Aevex7q3iRIY5bV3N9gx0WAkNBMi4&access_token=' . $access_token;
echo $inboxUrl . "<br />";
$homepage = file_get_contents($inboxUrl);
echo "file content : <pre>";
print_r($homepage);
```

Answer (score 0):

> YouTube's video responses feature has been retired as explained in
>   this [announcement](http://youtubecreator.blogspot.com/2013/08/so-long-video-responsesnext-up-better.html). While existing video responses are still available,
>   YouTube no longer supports the ability to retrieve a list of video
>   responses for a video, to upload new video responses, or to delete
>   video responses, though you can delete the video that was used in a
>   video response. Consequently, these functions are also no longer
>   supported in the API.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_responses

Comment: so can we do this using Data API version 3?. I have researched on V3 also but could'nt get any solution for this.

Comment: Nop, it was removed definitively :(

Comment: i want to user message and video sharing... video response??? please see this link https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_messages?hl=en#Retrieving_messages i want to use the features of this link